# Does Db2 support “accent insensitive” collations?

Tags: db2

In Microsoft SQL Server, it's possible to specify an "accent insensitive" collation (for a database, table or column). Is this possible in Db2?

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?

Comment: Linux red hat, Db2 10.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [Unicode Collation Algorithm based collations](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/r0050489.html) article.
Collating sequence is specified at the database creation time and can't be changed.

See the 'COLLATE USING *locale-sensitive-collation*' clause of the [CREATE DATABASE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001941.html) command.

There is no way to specify collation sequence at the table or column level, but you can use the [COLLATION_KEY_BIT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050491.html) function to compare string expressions.

```
select 
  case when c1=c2 then 1 else 0 end r1
, case when COLLATION_KEY_BIT(c1, 'CLDR181_EO_S1')=COLLATION_KEY_BIT(c2, 'CLDR181_EO_S1') then 1 else 0 end r2
from table(values ('Café', 'Cafe')) t(c1, c2);

R1 R2
-- --
 0  1
```

If your database had CLDR181_EO_S1 collation, the result in the 1-st column would be 1.